# a nashorn engine bug?

Tags: java, javascript, java-8, nashorn

i try to execute this simple short scripts to test nashorn :

```
basedir="/cassandara2/cassandra"
ba="/cassandara2/cassandra/lib/ST4-4.0.8.jar";
lib = "";
lib += '      <root url="jar://' + ba.replace(basedir, "$PROJECT_DIR");
print(lib);
```

it works perfectly but when i add sign **$** after **"$PROJECT_DIR"** ==> **"$PROJECT_DIR$"**  , i got this error:

```
> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range:
> 13    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:646)     at
> jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.NativeRegExp.appendReplacement(NativeRegExp.java:738)
>   at
> jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.NativeRegExp.replace(NativeRegExp.java:674)
>   at
> 
> jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.NativeString.replace(NativeString.java:763)
> bla...
```

Is it a bug of jdk 8 nashorn ( i used jdk8 u45) by this code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
            ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("nashorn");

            Object eval = engine.eval("load(\"" + "script/demo.js" + "\");");
            System.out.println(eval);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bug filed.  https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8081608 $ at the end of replace string causes index out of range error

```javascript
js> "string".replace("i", "$");
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1
jjs> "string".replace("i", "$ ");
str$ ng
```

Comment: This was fixed it 8u20.

Comment: i got it ! tks u very much ! Don't thinks there 're too many bugs in jdk :( ! bored! accepted your correct answer !

Answer (score 2):

it is not an answer, I have not enough points, but you have regexp exception and `$` character is regexp special character. Try to escape it, e.g. `'\\\$'`.

Comment: i think regex is not problem at here because this string contains 2 "$" sign !! why $PROJECT_DIR work but $PROJECT_DIR$ not work

Comment: try to test. I just saw the exception and made some decisions. When you are working with regexps you should be careful with regexp special characters.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this with 2 different JVM versions (jdk SE 1.8.0_60-ea-b16 and jdk SE 1.8.0_45-b14) and it worked perfectly outputting both $ signs before and after PROJECT_DIR with no exceptions.

Can you give us some more details such as what JDK implementation, OS, 32/64 bit JDK

There must be some underlying problem you are having but as a fix you can try the following

replace this JS line:

```
lib += '      <root url="jar://' + ba.replace(basedir, "$PROJECT_DIR$");
```

with either of these escape sequences

```
lib += '      <root url="jar://' + ba.replace(basedir, "\$PROJECT_DIR\$");
//or
lib += '      <root url="jar://' + ba.replace(basedir, "$$PROJECT_DIR$$");
```

Comment: I tested in Mac Os x ( 64 bit ) . And jdk version : jdk8 u45 .

Answer (score 1):

This is [a bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8044612) in the original JDK 1.8.0 release. It was fixed in the 8u20 update release.

It's strange that you report seeing this bug with Java 8u45, because that version definitely contains the fix:

```
jdk1.8.0_45/bin/jjs
jjs> "string".replace("i", "$");
str$ng
```

Could it be you have an older JDK 8 release on your path?

Comment: i got it ! tks u very much ! Don't thinks there 're too many bugs in jdk :( ! bored!